# How to randomise a JavaScript array and make sure sequential items are not the same

Tags: javascript, shuffle

I have an array of questions, some of these questions can be the same.

```
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Happy"},
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Fun"}, 
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Enjoyable"},   
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Pleasurable"},  
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Ecstatic"},
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Sad"},   
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Tedious"},
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Annoying"},  
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Depressing"},
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Unhappy"},
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Happy"},
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Fun"},
 {"choice":"attributes","text":"Enjoyable"},
```

At the moment I am randomising the array using a FisherYatesShuffle() What I really need to do though is after the shuffle go over the list and make sure that no two sequential items are the same, any idea?

e.g. We never get

```
{"choice":"attributes","text":"Happy"},
{"choice":"attributes","text":"Happy"},
```

EDIT to clear up some of the questions. 
All the items in the array must be retained.

Comment: Why not just dedup the list first, then shuffle?

Comment: You might like taking a look at http://underscorejs.org/   You can shuffle easily and also dedup. Lot of really powerful functions.

Comment: How about going through the array, looking for two adjacent items and picking one and randomly swapping it with another element in the array. Then start going through the array again (from the beginning) and keep doing this until you get through the entire array.

Comment: It might depend on the characteristics of your list but the simplest solution would be to shuffle again until it's OK.

Comment: Is it possible to have so many duplicates that it is not actually possible to arrange the array in such a way that there are no sequential duplicates?

Comment: To people who are suggesting removing duplicates: that's not what the question is about.

Comment: Zeke, I need to keep the items just not show them back to back. Pete your idea sounds the best solution have you got a basic example?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: I believe he actually wants duplicates, they shouldn't be sequentially. For example in a randomized playlist if the same song is twice in the playlist the shuffled playlist should still contain the song twice.

Comment: @TheAlbear I don't get what you mean by a basic example : Pete's solution is just an easy to implement algorithm. Apart the whole ready to use code what would you need ?

Comment: Fair. I guess I'd loop the set at that point. Seems like there are alternative solutions that make the problem simpler. But I don't know the big picture.

Comment: @jbabey: That only happens if a distinct value occurs more than N/2 times. If a value occurs exactly N/2 times you can use it as separator between the other items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep shuffling your array until there are no two sequential items that are the same:

```
var shuffled = false,
    i = 0,
    length = myArray.length,
    previous;
while(!shuffled){                            // repeat this until we have a shuffled array.
    myArray = FisherYatesShuffle(myArray);   // (Assuming you have that function)
    shuffled = true;                         // first, assume the array is shuffled,
    for(i = 0; i < length && shuffled; i++){ // Then loop through the array to check if it is indeed shuffled.
        if(previous && previous.text == myArray[i].text){
            shuffled = false;                // If it isn't shuffled, set shuffled to false.
        }                                    // This breaks the for loop, and tries to shuffle the array again.
        previous = myArray[i];
    }
}
```

The advantage is that it only shuffles once, if the loop proves to be shuffled sufficiently the first time, but if there's a lot of items that are the same, it can iterate over the loop often, as it has to randomly return a properly shuffled array from the `FisherYatesShuffle`.